# Extend Coffeescript subclass function from parent in marionette

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript, marionette

I've got a "FormView" class in my Marionette application that sets up a lot of things for form submissions around my app. I use it every time there is a form. I've also got some helpers that I want to pass into every form template via the `templateHelpers` method, but I also want to be able to add additional `templateHelpers` in the children. Like so:

```
class Views.FormView extends Marionette.ItemView
  templateHelpers: ->
    helpers: Marionette.Concerns.Helpers

class Views.NewUser extends Views.FormView
  templateHelpers: ->
    variable: @something
```

I want to be able to access both `@variable` and `@helpers` from the template for `NewUser`. Additionally, I know how to handle this (via `_.extends`) if `templateHelpers` is an object, but I need it to be a function.

Is it possible? And if so, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Backbone, when you inherit from another class, Backbone will give the subclass a `__super__` property (double underscore at both ends) which is the prototype of the parent class. So from within your `Views.NewUser` class, you can get the prototype via `View.NewUser.__super__`. Then, you can call `templateHelpers` on that object. Here's how I did it ([live example at JSbin](http://jsbin.com/vohulohuzu/edit?js,console)):

```
Views = {}

class Views.FormView extends Marionette.ItemView
  templateHelpers: ->
    helpers: "Parent Value"
  logHelpers: ->
    console.log @templateHelpers()

class Views.NewUser extends Views.FormView
  templateHelpers: ->
    variable: "Child Value"
  logHelpers: ->
    console.log @templateHelpers()
    console.log Views.NewUser.__super__.templateHelpers()


formView = new Views.FormView()

formView.logHelpers() // { helpers: "Parent Value" }

newUser = new Views.NewUser()

newUser.logHelpers()

// { variable: "Child Value" }, { helpers: "Parent Value" }
```

You could then use `_.extend` to extend one with the other; maybe like this:

```
initialize: ->
    @helpers = _.extend @templateHelpers(),
        Views.NewUser.__super__.templateHelpers()
```

Comment: That is very interesting, but I'd still prefer it if I were able to somehow extend it from the PARENT class. Just because I know i'm going to forget to extend it from the child class when I create a new instance.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, you can't extend a subclass **from within** a parent class (in any language). Also, the `initialize` method will be called automatically when you create a new instance of the child class, so if you do the  `_.extend` in that method, you don't have to remember to do it. You can just use the `@helpers` (or whatever you call it) property right away.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that when you say "parent" you mean "parent view" rather than OO ancestor.
What you want to achieve can be done by doing the following:
1. Pass the data object from parent to child view using the itemViewOptions (or childViewOptions in newer Marionette). It can contain functions.
2. In you child view you can do the following:

```
templateHelpers: ->
  _.extend super(), @options.someOptionsFromParent
```